# How can I unlock dogtags for Battlefield 3 if I own other games in the series?

Tags: battlefield-3, origin

The BattleField 3 knowledgebase [says](https://help.ea.com/article/bf3-gameplay-and-items):

**Will veteran ranks and status earned in previous BF games grant bonuses in Battlefield 3?**
Yes, you will have unlocked a silenced M1911 pistol.  Also you will receive dog tags associated with previous games if you registered those games.

I have Battlefield 1942 (all expansions), Battlefield 2, Battlefield 2142 and an accout on Battlefield Play4Free - so how do I "register these games"? Do I have to put the CD key into Origin or something else? Is it even possible to get the tags after so long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go here: http://www.battlefieldbadcompany2.com/veteran
2. Log in with your EA credentials (same you use to login to BF3
   battlelog)
3. Go to the "Veteran" tab, and click the game you want to add.
4. Then click "Force refresh veteran status"

Done.

Comment: Thanks - I'm having issues with (once I've signed in) it asking me to "Select a persona" and when I click on "Save" the page seems to hang for quite a while...is this an issue or will it take a while?

Comment: I have go the same problem than @tombull89 :(

Comment: @Techbrunch, try setting your location to US rather than yours...that's what worked for me in the end.

Answer (score 5):

It should be.

I played BF:BC (which I purchased on steam) and it gave me the 1911. **As long as the account you used for your old bf games are registered under the same email than the one you use for bf3**, battlelog should detect your old games. No need to register them through origin or do anything special.

If it doesn't, it means there is a bug somewhere, I would suggest contacting EA support to get these bonuses.

You can always try registering your old CD keys through origin to force Battlelog to see them.

Comment: Yep, it's tied to your EA/Origin account.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i got battlefield 1942 installed through origin. Battlelog just saw my game and gave me the rewards. Logically you should install the game through origin. Seeing that every battlefield game is of EA that shouldn't be a problem.